# X11 BadAlloc Error from OpenGL

Tags: c, opengl, x11

I'm learning OpenGL using [this book](http://openglbook.com/the-book/).  I'm trying to run the first example, which is [here](http://openglbook.com/the-book/chapter-1-getting-started/#toc-first-steps).  It compiles fine, but when I try to run it, I get an X11 BadAlloc error:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadAlloc (insufficient resources for operation)
Major opcode of failed request:  128 (GLX)
Minor opcode of failed request:  34 ()
Serial number of failed request:  38
Current serial number in output stream:  39
```

As far as I can tell, this error is caused when glutCreateWindow is called.  I don't know if this is an issue with X itself or with my graphics card, which is a nVidia geForce 310.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your graphics drivers don't support OpenGL version 4.0.

```
glutInitContextVersion(4, 0);
```

I changed it to 3.3:

```
glutInitContextVersion(3, 3);
```

and it works fine. You can get your OpenGL version from `glxinfo`.

Comment: Huh.  Thank you.  That makes sense.  I guess I'll look into what I can do to get it compatible...

Comment: It usually comes down to updating your drivers. If this doesn't work, there's nothing you can do. But anyway, stick to 3.3; 4.0 won't bring you much if you're a beginner.